# Python/CGI on IIS - find user ID

Tags: python, iis, cgi

I have a very basic CGI based front end hosted on an IIS server. 
I'm trying to find the users within my shop that have accessed this site. 
All users on the network sign on with their LAN (Windows) credentials and the same session would be used to access the site.

The python getpass module (obviously) returns only the server name so is there a way to find the user names of the visitors to the site?

The stack is Python 2.7 on IIS 8.0, Windows Server 2012

Answer (score 1):

When using Windows authentication on IIS, the server variables should contain the username in two variables: `AUTH_USER` and `REMOTE_USER`

CGI offers access to all server variables, check your Python docs on how to access them.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I tried that. For some reason those variables are assigned empty strings.

Comment: Some of the other internal sites have an ASP front end and use Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER") to get the current user which works well. In Python, os.environ['LOGON_USER'] returns an empty string. I tried AUTH_USER and REMOTE_USER as well but no luck:(